# How Do I Display Arrays in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, spacebars, meteor-helper

So my problem is that my array is not printing from my javascript.  I'm using meteor.

js:

```
Template.CreateDeckCard.events({
            'submit form':function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                console.log("Card Submitted");
                var cardFront = event.target.CardFront.value;
                var cardBack = event.target.CardBack.value;

            tempAddDeck[tempAddDeck.length] = {front : cardFront},{back : cardBack}
            //debug 

            //reset two name spaces
            event.target.CardFront.value="";
            event.target.CardBack.value="";

            //after we have cards we update below

        }
});
Template.CreateDeckCard.helpers ({
    tempAdd: function() {
        return tempAddDeck.find();
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="cardFronts" name="existCardBack">
    <ul>
        {{#each tempAdd}}
             <li>{{cardFront}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="cardBacks" name="existCardFront">
     <ul>
         {{#each tempAdd}}
             <li>{{cardBack}}</li>
         {{/each}}
     </ul>
</div>
```

Nothing is being displayed when text is submitted via the form for some reason.  As a note there exists a var tempAddDeck declared at the beginning of the JavaScript file.

Answer (score 0):

From your question

```
As a note there exists a var tempAddDeck declared at the beginning of the JavaScript file.
```

I suppose `tempAddDeck` is declared as array like

```
var tempAddDeck=[];
```

at top of js file then try

```
Template.CreateDeckCard.helpers ({
    tempAdd: function() {
        return tempAddDeck;
    }
});
```

**Note** `.find()` method is used on monog queries, it is not array method

Comment: That doesn't seem to fix it even without the `.find()` method.  The array was originally declared as `tempAddDeck = new Array();`

Comment: in your html file instead of `front` and `back` you're using `cardFront` and `cardBack` also if that doesn't work try `this.front` instead of simple front